# Find the next number value after a sublist in a list

Tags: python, list, variables

I have two lists called x and y.

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

y = [4, 5]
```

I am trying to find the list that starts with y and get the following item (6 in this case). Also, i want to do this with a custom function. It must work like below

```
my_func(y)
```

takes the y and returns the number that comes next and equalize a variable to the number. Like, variable = 6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this with lists and loops, it is probably quickest to do it with `numpy` arrays:

```py
import numpy as np
def get_next_value(x, y):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    num_to_check = y.shape[0]
    row_to_get_value = np.where((x[:,0:num_to_check] == y).sum(axis = 1) == num_to_check)
    desired_value = x[row_to_get_value, num_to_check]
         
    # Handle error if no match is found
    if desired_value.size > 0:
        return desired_value.item()
    else:
        return None

x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
y = [4, 5]
get_next_value(x, y)
# 6
```

Comment: You can do `next((tail for *head, tail in x if head == y), None)` I don't think the numpy code would be faster

Comment: @DaniMesejo that's a nice approach. I suppose speed depends on the size of the list. There is obviously a massive overhead to type conversion if it is only a few values like in this case. With a large list/array my experience is that numpy is generally quicker than looping over lists.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this should work for you:

```
x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
y = [4, 5]

def my_func(y):
    output, ly = [], len(y)
    for l in x: 
        if l[:ly] == y: output.append(l[ly])
    return output

my_func(y)
```

Output:

```
[6]
```